# Python dynamic inheritance from Exceptions

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, inheritance, decorator

I'm trying to create a custom Exception which can inherit from all the Exceptions.
I've used a wrapper, here's my code:

```
def _MyError(_type, message=None, *args, **kwargs):
    class MyError(_type, object):
        def __init__(self, *_args, **_kwargs):
        super(MyError, self).__init__(self, message, *_args, **_kwargs)
        return

    return MyError(*args, **kwargs)


if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    try:
        raise _MyError(KeyError, message="ooops")
    except MyError as e:
        print "MyError occurred. ", e.message
    except BaseException:
        print "MyError not recognized.\n"

    try:
        raise _MyError(IndexError, message="ooops")
    except IndexError as e:
        print "MyError occurred. ", e.message
    except BaseException:
        print "MyError not recognized.\n"
    
    exit
```

Output:

```
MyError not recognized.
MyError not recognized.
```

Suggestions?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather tricky problem. The issue is that the very creation of your specialized MyError fails with an `IndexError`. Because an `IndexError` is not a `KeyError`, it passes right through the attempt to catch it and instead is caught as a `BaseException`.

```
def _MyError(_type, *args, **kwargs):
    class MyError(_type, object):
        def __init__(self, *_args, **_kwargs):
            super(MyError, self).__init__(self, *_args, **_kwargs)
            # Error on above line (IndexError from kwargs not accepted)

    return MyError(*args, **kwargs) # Error goes through here

try:
    raise _MyError(KeyError, message='hello')
    # raise never gets invoked, IndexError on calling _MyError
except KeyError: # IndexError != KeyError. This clause is skipped
    print 'KeyError'
# except BaseException: 
    # print 'BaseException'
# Commenting out the above lines will throw the error instead of catching it
```

You should instead create your error like so:

```
raise _MyError(KeyError, 'hello')
```

Comment: Check the code... I tried to catch _My(type, args) as MyError and then I tried  to catch it as its type...

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions does not accept `message`; causes `super(MyError, self).__init__(self, *_args, **_kwargs)` fail.

```
>>> IndexError(message='asdf')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: exceptions.IndexError does not take keyword arguments
```

You need to convert `message` to positional argument:

```
def _MyError(_type, *args, **kwargs):
    class MyError(_type, object):
        def __init__(self, message=None):
            super(MyError, self).__init__(self, message)

    return MyError(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: @NicholasRoveda, Did you try the code in the answer? http://asciinema.org/a/0sgbr96z0x9gxpa0ysfnufqve

Answer (score 1):

When I try your code in Python 2.7 I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    except MyError as e:
NameError: name 'MyError' is not defined
```

This is not surprising, because the name `MyError` does not exist at the file-level scope where you are trying to catch it.

Also consider that you're creating a new class each time you call the `_MyError()` function. So even if there *were* a `MyError` class available to use in the `except` block, it would almost certainly be the *wrong* class (albeit with the same name).

I suspect you might want to create a "root" `MyError` class, and then create a `MyCustomError` class in your function. You could then catch the `MyError` (base) class in your `exception` block and proceed from there.

**EDIT**

Per your comment, you might be able to do something like this:

```
class MyError:
    """Marker class for mixin."""
    pass

def my_error(_type, message=None, *args, **kwargs):
    class _MySubclass(_type, MyError):
        def __init__(self, *_args, **_kwargs):
            super(_MySubclass, self).__init__(message, *_args, **_kwargs)

    return _MySubclass(*args, **kwargs)

try:
    raise my_error(KeyError, message="key error")
except MyError as e:
    print "MyError occurred: ", e.message
except BaseException:
    print "Unknown error:", str(e)

try:
    raise my_error(IndexError, message="index error")
except MyError as e:
    print "MyError occurred: ", e.message
except BaseException:
    print "Unknown error:", str(e)
```

Comment: Yeah, I see what u mean... It's also possible to do it only with decorators and direct catch as I'm trying to?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a class factory to build your error [type dynamically, as explained in the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type).

```py
def error_factory(name, *base_errors):
    """Dynamically create custom Error class."""
    assert all(issubclass(e, Exception) for e in base_errors)

    return type(name, base_errors, {})


try:
    something()
except KeyError:
    MyError = error_factory("MyError", KeyError)
    raise MyError("A problem occured!")  # this error is also a `KeyError`
```